# Trying to batch AddMessage to an Azure Queue

Tags: multithreading, azure, queue, batch-processing

I've got about 50K messages I wish to add to an azure queue.

I'm not sure if the code I have is safe. It feels/smells bad.

Basically, give a collection of POCO's, serialize the POCO to some json, then add that json text to the queue.

```
public void AddMessage(T content)
{
    content.ShouldNotBe(null);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
    var message = new CloudQueueMessage(json);
    Queue.AddMessage(message);
}

public void AddMessages(ICollection<T> contents)
{
    contents.ShouldNotBe(null);
    Parallel.ForEach(contents, AddMessage);
}
```

Can someone tell me what I should be doing to fix this up -- and most importantly, why?

I feel that the Queue might not be thread safe, in this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things I have observed regarding `Parallel.ForEach` and dealing with Azure Storage (my experience has been with uploading blobs/blocks in parallel):

- Azure storage operations are Network (IO) based operations and not processor intensive operations. If I am not mistaken, `Parallel.ForEach` is more suitable for processor intensive applications.
- Another thing we noticed with uploading a large number of blobs (or blocks) using `Parallel.ForEach` is that we started to get a lot of `Timeout` exceptions and actually slowed down the entire operation. I believe the reason for this is when you iterate over a collection with large number of items using this approach, you're essentially handling the control to underlying framework which decides how to deal with that collection. In this case, a lot of `Context Switching` will take place which slows down the operation. Not sure how this would work in your scenario considering the payload is smaller.

My recommendation would be have the application control the number of parallel threads it can spawn. A good criteria would be the number of logical processor. Another good criteria would be the number of ports IE can open. So you would spawn that many number of parallel threads. Then you could either wait for all threads to finish to spawn next set of parallel threads or start a new thread as soon as one task finishes.

Pseudo Code:

```
    ICollection<string> messageContents;
    private void AddMessages()
    {
        int maxParallelThreads = Math.Min(Environment.ProcessorCount, messageContents.Count);
        if (maxParallelThreads > 0)
        {
            var itemsToAdd = messageContents.Take(maxParallelThreads);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (var i = 0; i < maxParallelThreads; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    AddMessage(itemsToAdd[i]);
                    RemoveItemFromCollection();
                }));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            AddMessages();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. So what's the other option (code) to control the number of parallel threads? 2. What does IE have to do with this?

Comment: Regarding #1, we just picked the processor count and used that (not really scientific, I know :)). Regarding #2, my understanding is that network operations somehow use IE infrastructure (I may be wrong there).

Comment: Picked the process count? for what? sample code? (not about picking the proc count .. but using that value in what?)

Comment: Added some pseudo code. Not very elegant but should give you an idea about how you can control the number of parallel threads.

Comment: AH! using `Task` - gotcha :)

Comment: You are right about the cpu intensive thing. What I have done alot for blobs is to use ActionBlocks from TPL building Blocks with great succes. When at a pc i Will paste an example. I have not experienced timeouts even when uploading thousans small files concurrent.

Comment: I prefer the SemaphoreSlim class.  Doesn't read as well, but it's solid.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine to me at a high level. Gaurav's additions make sense, so you have more controls over the parallel processing of your requests. Make sure you add some form of retry logic, and perhaps setting the [DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) to something greater than its default value (which is 2). You may also consider adding multiple Azure Queues across multiple storage accounts if you hit a form of throttling, depending on the type of errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to add a large number of non-POCO/string messages in bulk/batch to a queue, an alternate/better solution will be to add the list of messages as a single message or blob, and then in a queue/blob trigger traverse & add each message to a [seperate] queue.

Answer (score -1):

```
var maxDegreeOfParallelism = Math.Min(Environment.ProcessorCount,cloudQueueMessageCollection.Count());
var parallelOptions=new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism };
Parallel.ForEach(cloudQueueMessageCollection, parallelOptions,
                    async (m) => await AddMessageAsync(queue, connectionStringOrKey, m));
```

Comment: refer to @gauravmantri 's answer above. Use `tasks` over `Parallel.ForEach` when doing I/O bound parallelism. Also, you don't need to specify the `maxDegree` unless u want to RESTRICT the number of cores (eg. use only 1 core, for debugging purposes OR for granular control of the program on some specific hardware).